# preg_match_all not matching href section correctly

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm having a problem matching the href section of a link using preg_match_all, currently it is capturing 3 sections (full link, url only, link text only) which is perfect but the url only part is capturing any other tags located after the href tag.

Also how do I make the "href" text case insensitive?

**Code:**

```
$content = '<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a> is a search engine. <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" title="yahoo" target="_blank">Yahoo</a> is a search engine.';

preg_match_all('/<a href="([^<]*)">([^<]*)<\/a>/', $content, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
            [1] => <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" title="yahoo" target="_blank">Yahoo</a>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.google.com" target="_blank
            [1] => http://www.yahoo.com" title="yahoo" target="_blank
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Google
            [1] => Yahoo
        )

)
```

Comment: [Do not use regexes to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/344643). Use an [XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Ah that never gets old :D

Comment: I'll look into domdocument, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your starting out looking for the > and not taking in to account any other attributes. try

```
/<a href="([^"]*)"[^>]+>([^<]*)<\/a>/
```

this will now pull out the href, then skip over the rest of the attributes, and then pull the html right up the next tag

Comment: Will this also match urls like this: <a target="_blank" href="URL">Text</a>